# Literals in django template language?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, literals

If I want some text to appear literally in a Django template, e.g.

```
{{Image.jpg|title}}
```

and I want that text to be output (not interpretated) in the HTML, how do I do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the `{% templatetag %}` template tag

```
{% templatetag openvariable %}Image.jpg|title{% templatetag closevariable %}
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag

Answer (score 1):

You could start it with an HTML entity. e.g.:

```
&#123;{Image.jpg|title}}
```

However, I can only imagine this means you are writing content in your templates, which is normally not advisable.